# preg_replace not catching pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Trying to take in a large paragraph string and format a key word.  My code is as follows:

```
function envisio($content){
    $env = '/(\s)+( (WORD|word|Word)(\s)?(AB|ab|Ab) )(\s)+/';
    $new = preg_replace ($env , '<span class="word">Word</span><span class="abb">AB</span>', $content);
    return $new;
}
```

I'm trying to catch all occurrences of "WordAB" (WORDAB, WORD AB, WordAB, Word AB etc.) and replace with the formatted html string.  However, the function is not catching any of the occurances.  Is it an error I am missing in my regex?

Comment: What `$content` are you passing to this function?

Comment: Without your example string, it is difficult to give you an answer.

Comment: an example string would be "Random string with WordAB in it somewhere";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/word\s*ab/i` case insensitive.

```
function envisio($content, $first, $second, $nowraps = array()) {

    $lookahead  = '';
    $lookbehind = '';

    if(count($nowraps) > 0) {
        $lookahead  = sprintf('(?![%s])', implode('', $nowraps));
        $lookbehind = sprintf('(?<![%s])', implode('', $nowraps));
    }

    $regex = sprintf('/%s%s\s?%s%s/i', $lookbehind, $first, $second, $lookahead);
    $replacement = sprintf('<span class="word">Word</span><span class="abb">AB</span>', $first, $second);
    return preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $content);
}

$str = '"WordAB" (WORDAB, WORD AB, WordAB, Word AB etc.) http://example.com/wordab/?a=wordab&b=WORDAB';

echo envisio($str, 'word', 'ab', array('\/', '\&', '?', '='));
```

Comment: This may or may not be exactly what the OP wants though since things like "wOrD" and "worD" would match. Regardless, I like this method and believe it to be the simplest.

Comment: I like this too but I need to make sure there is whitespace before and after.

Comment: I ended up useing /\s+(word\s?it/i worked like a charm.  was trailing \s that was causing issues with name followed by end of string or period.

Comment: @jppower175 I've added a rudimentary function to help solve the issue of URLs.  It uses look-arounds so you don't have to post process the result with any trimming.

Comment: I like this function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function envisio($content){
    $env = '~\s+(?:WORD|[Ww]ord)\s?(?:AB|[aA]b)\s+/';
    $new = preg_replace($env, ' <span class="word">Word</span><span'
                             .' class="abb">AB</span> ', $content);
    return $new;
}
```

Your error comes probably from the spaces part. *( `) )(\s)+` need at least 2 spaces.)*

You can try a more general pattern too:

```
$env = '~\s*\bword\s*ab\b\s*~i';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code:

```
$pattern = '/(\s)+( (WORD|word|Word)(\s)?(AB|ab|Ab) )(\s)+/';
$replacement = '<span class="word">Word</span><span class="abb">AB</span>';
$new = preg_replace ($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

where `$content` is the paragraph in question. I presume that what you're looking for is a "word" and then a "code" (could be run-together, could be on different lines, could be any case), and replace them with a fixed text? With `\s+(` you're demanding one or more whitespace followed by a regular space (blank)... is that what you wanted? Assuming that the word and code you want to match get replaced by fixed text (in the `<span>`s), something like

```
$pattern = '/\bword\s?ab\b/si`;
$replacement = (as before)
$new = (as before)
```

might do it. The /s flag should span you across line breaks, and the /i flag is case-independent. \s? allows 0 or 1 whitespace between the terms -- you might want to replace it with \s* if there could be 0 or more whitespaces. I'm not sure if I'm using \b appropriately here, but the intent is to isolate a word phrase without having to explicitly specify what can or cannot come before or after what you're looking for.

Comment: the words i am looking for "WordAB" is a company name that is also the domain for there website and email.  Sometimes people type a space between the "Word" and "AB" sometimes not. I need to catch all instances except were it is used in a url or email address which is why I wanted the whitespace before and after.  So when it is a stand alone word it gets the html format